# Date selection with price - without commerce

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, commerce, datetime

I need a option to let users set up dates and price when creating node with unlimited number of entries.

For example:

"from: 15/01/2015 to 20/02/2015 - Price = 50 USD"

from: 21/02/2015 to 15/03/2015 - Price = 70 USD

from: 16/03/2015 to 15/05/2015 - Price = 90 USD

It would be nice if could look user friendly too since users will make atleast 7-8 entries.

Something like "from: __________ to __________ : price __________"

Instead of underline it should be date popup and for price i would use integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module and [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module.

1. Navigate to manage fields under your node type
2. Create a new field with field type of Field collection
3. Set the number of values to unlimited under the field you created in step 2
4. Navigate to /admin/structure/field-collections and select Manage Fields under the field collection you just created in step 2.
5. Select Manage Fields
6. Add From Date Field
7. Add To Date Field
8. Add Price Field